# Heroku prompts cannot GET/ error for nodejs

Tags: node.js, heroku

While trying to follow Heroku getting started for node.js tutorial, I reach the part where they asked me to Define config vars and provision a database. When I finished the configuration as the walkthrough mentioned, I tried to open them using `heroku open times` and `heroku open db` but all I was an error that states `Cannot GET /times` and `Cannot GET /db`.

As I am new to using nodejs I have no idea why the application is returning this error, I have tried to look up solution but I can't find anything that is closely related to the issue that I have.

Below is my index.js

```
const cool = require('cool-ascii-faces')
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const app = express();

express()
  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
  .set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
  .set('view engine', 'ejs')
  .get('/', (req, res) => res.render('pages/index'))
  .get('/cool', (req, res) => res.send(cool()))
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`))

app.get('/times', (req, res) => {
  let result = ''
  const times = process.env.TIMES || 5
  for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    result += i + ' '
  }
  res.send(result)
})

const { Pool } = require('pg');
const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: true
});

app.get('/db', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const client = await pool.connect()
    const result = await client.query('SELECT * FROM test_table');
    res.render('pages/db', result);
    client.release();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.send("Error " + err);
  }
});
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "node-js-getting-started",
  "version": "0.3.0",
  "description": "A sample Node.js app using Express 4",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.9.1"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "node test.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cool-ascii-faces": "^1.3.4",
    "ejs": "^2.5.6",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "pg": "^7.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "request": "^2.81.0",
    "tape": "^4.7.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "heroku",
    "express"
  ],
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

this is my .gitignore

```
# Node build artifacts
node_modules
npm-debug.log

# Local development
*.env
*.dev
.DS_Store

# Docker
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
```

and my procfile

```
web: node index.js
```

Any help is appreciated and sorry for the long post. :)

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue. I can open /times in local but not in deployed heroku. And I can't open /db in either.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my variant of index.js. Actually you just have to rewrite proposed modifications with Express 4.

```
const cool = require('cool-ascii-faces')
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const pg = require('pg')

const config = {
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: true
};

const pool = new pg.Pool(config)

express()
  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
  .set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
  .set('view engine', 'ejs')
  .get('/', (req, res) => res.render('pages/index'))
  .get('/cool', (req, res) => res.send(cool()))
  .get('/times', function (req, res) {
    let result = ''
    const times = process.env.TIMES || 5
    for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      result += i + ' '
    }
    res.send(result)
  })
  .get('/db1', function (req, res, next) {
    pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Can not connect to the DB" + err)
      }
      client.query('SELECT * FROM test_table;', function (err, result) {
        done()
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
        res.status(200).send(result.rows)
      })
    })
  })
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`))
```